# BUG - Arrow icon overlaps other taskbar icons

Tags: windows, taskbar, operating-systems, icons, windows-11

The image below shows a duplicate arrow icon (normally used to show hidden icons) overlapping with the microphone icon when it is displayed outside of the collapsed group. This happens for any icon displayed outside the group. Anyone know a fix?

[image: Arrow icon overlaid on Microphone icon - BUG]

Comment: Make a new, test Windows User Account. Log into the new account, do a basic setup and see if the extra up arrow occurs in a new Windows User Acccount.